# devise_token_auth how to identify a user by token

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to use `gem devise_token_auth`  and working on a mobile client api, two questions:

1) How should i identify a user? My current understanding is on a http request header set **access_token** is this right?

But seems from the source code i should provide for **uid**,  **access_token**,  **client**[link](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/v0.1.30/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb)

`uid        = request.headers['did']
    @token     = request.headers['access-token']
    @client_id = request.headers['client']`

2) i can find a **user.tokens** like below:

```
 {"AOYZdDmwI7WQr8I6T4PpPw"=>{"token"=>"$2a$10$C/5f3JV7.9DZG8w.ggdCPelB6kzitWuGK4rfozHv15Hhf/x9DaCcO", "expiry"=>1473485374, "last_token"=>"$2a$10$abctsIP5bHPIm2nMXFTUH.1jPWQ5LiGTTrENjoqihWgcCkwRqbxb6", "updated_at"=>"2016-08-27T13:29:34.948+08:00"}}
```

which is `client` and which is **access-token**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
headers = JSON.parse(cookies['authHeaders'])
uid = headers['uid']
token = headers['access-token']
client_id = headers['client']
user = User.find_by_uid(uid)
if !user || !user.valid_token?(token, client_id)
  render json: {error: "Usuario no autorizado."}, status: 401
end
```